# Remove IntRanges from ArrayList and split the result

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist

Imagine an arraylist which contains numbers from 1 to 100:

```
val numbers = ArrayList<Int>()

for (x in 1..100) {
    numbers.add(x)
}
```

Then we have these IntRanges also:

```
val range1 = 5..10
val range2 = 15..20
val range3 = 80..90
```

I want to remove these ranges from ArrayList then split the result into IntRanges. The final result should look like this:

```
val result1 = 1..4
val result2 = 11..14
val result3 = 21..79
val result4 = 91..100
```

What solution do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite fun homework you have there :)

First things first here is the answer:

```
val allItems = (1..100).toList()
val ranges = listOf(5..10, 15..20, 80..90).sortedBy { it.first }
val removedRanges = allItems - (ranges.map { it.toList() }.reduce { a, b-> a + b })
val result = removedRanges
    .mapIndexed { i, it -> it to i }
    .groupBy { it.first - it.second }
    .map { it.value.map { it.first } }
    .map { it.first() .. it.last() }

Log.w("here are your ranges", result.joinToString { "$it" })
```

Lets first talk how this relatively shortcode works, this is by no means perfect solution but it allows you to operate on "list" instead of ranges for starting list.

## removedRanges

In kotlin we can change range to list with all of its element with simple method .toList() and we can do simple math with such lists, aka listOf(1,2,3) + listOf(5) will result in [1,2,3,5].
Operation reduce allows you to transform a set of T to single element T by doing operation, in this case, we just want to sum all ranges and remove them from starting set
thus removeRanges will be [1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 12, ...

## result

The idea here is quite simple, how to detect continuous ranges withing list of integers?
We group them by the difference between their index and their value.
Finally, map them to list and finally back to ranges.

Cheers and have fun. Sadly even with the correct answer teacher might be asking you how did you come up with this idea :) ...